How to Prevent Duplicate Entries in a Many-to-Many Relationship with Gorm
I'm working on a Go application using Gorm and Fiber, managing users and their languages in a many-to-many relationship. Below are my model definitions:
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID         uuid.UUID  `gorm:"type:uuid;"`
    Name       string     `gorm:"not null" json:"name"`
    Languages  []Language `gorm:"many2many:translator_languages;" json:"languages"`
}

type Language struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `gorm:"not null" json:"name"`
    Code string `gorm:"not null" json:"code"`
}

And here is my function for updating a user, including their languages:
func updateUser(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    var updatedUser User
    if err := c.BodyParser(&updatedUser); err != nil {
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusBadRequest).JSON(fiber.Map{"error": "Invalid request payload"})
    }

    userID := c.Params("id")

    var existingUser User
    if err := db.First(&existingUser, "id = ?", userID).Error; err != nil {
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusNotFound).JSON(fiber.Map{"error": "User not found"})
    }

    existingUser.Name = updatedUser.Name
    existingUser.Languages = updatedUser.Languages

    if err := db.Save(&existingUser).Error; err != nil {
        return c.Status(fiber.StatusInternalServerError).JSON(fiber.Map{"error": "Failed to update user"})
    }

    return c.JSON(existingUser)
}

When updating a user's languages, this method can introduce duplicate entries in the Language table, which I want to avoid. I would like new entries to be added to the translator_languages join table (if they don't already exist for that user), but without creating duplicate language entries in the Language table.How can I achieve this?

Have you testet if it ACTUALLY produces duplicates? m:n tables usually are using composite primary keys consisting of two foreign keys. If GORM is doing it this way duplicates are not possible.
